# Cloud Firestore Query Array from Full String

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection in Firebase that contains multiple records, each containing a name and an array of strings for the record’s “keywords”. Example below.

```
Record_1
   name: Record 1
   keywords: [apple, orange, raspberry]
Record_2
   name: Record 2
   keywords: [orange, strawberry, raspberry]
Record_3
   name: Record 3
   keywords: [apple, pear, strawberry]


//Search String: “I would like an apple and an orange.”

//Returns results: Record_1 and Record_2
```

I would like to run the search from a user’s search string from a text field. Unfortunately this string may contain words that do not exist in any of the keywords array.

I would like to return the records that have all of the matching keywords from the search string, but not limit is due to the words that do not exist from the search string, in the arrays. Please see example “search string” and “returns results” above.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no single query that will do this for you.  You will have to make multiple [array_contains queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership), one for each string you're looking for.

```
collectionRef.where("keywords", "array-contains", "thing-to-look-for")
```

Then, you can merge the results of each of the queries on the client, in order to remove any duplicates.

Comment: What do you think about my answer? It would certainly work for just a few words, i.e. a small string, however, it would get a lot more complicated once you cannot expect exact matches.

Comment: The OP does not have "full text" to reach that requires a full text search engine. They have simple strings in an array to match exactly to find.

Comment: Have you set this up for yourself to see how much work it requires, how much it might cost, and if it actually works the way you expect?

Comment: No. I am happy to provide full disclosure on that (updated my answer to make it more clear). Anyway, I would still point out that Algolia exists for the case that the multiple `array-contains` queries do not work perfectly. Hence, I will leave my answer up, however, yours should be the go-to answer.